# From two scripts works only one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to solve the problem with two different scripts I don't know why the second one works while the first one doesn't. Then I am deleting the second script first one start working. Maybe you will find the solution.

```js
<script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
            $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal2) {
                    $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal2.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal3) {
                    $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal3.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal4) {
                    $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal4.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>
    
    
  <script>
        
  var exit = document.getElementById('close1');

  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == exit) {
       $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Due to overriding the window onclick function

Comment: this is normale , the second you've ovveriding the funcition in the second declaration , just combine all code in same function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, because you have two onClick handlers, therefore only one of them will work (they override each other)

Move the logic into one onClick handler.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == exit) {
    ...
  }
  if (event.target == modal) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the onclick function. try using `addEventlistener` instead.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // your first function
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // your second function
});
```

So in your case.

```
<script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal) {
      $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
      $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal3) {
      $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      modal3.style.display = "none"
    }
    if (event.target == modal4) {
      $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      modal4.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
</script>

<script>

var exit = document.getElementById('close1');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == exit) {
    $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');
var exit = document.getElementById('close1');

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
       if (event.target == exit) {
       $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal) {
            $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal2) {
                    $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal2.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal3) {
                    $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal3.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal4) {
                    $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal4.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>

  You can try this
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your if statements should stay inside of `window.onclick`  like this...

```
var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
  var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');

window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
            $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal2) {
                    $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal2.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal3) {
                    $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal3.style.display = "none";
      }
      if (event.target == modal4) {
                    $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal4.style.display = "none";
      }

if (event.target == exit) {
       $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign `window.onClick` *twice* and the second assignment overwrites the first, so it is as if the first one never existed.

You can use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead:

```
// First script
window.addEventListener('click', function() {...});

// Second script
window.addEventListener('click', function() {...});
```

Working demo:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(1); });
window.addEventListener('click', function() { console.log(2); });
```